# UPDATE is claiming that the database is locked

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine, sql-update

I can use any command but UPDATE. When I do Unity throws an error saying that the database is locked.  The command that I am executing is this:

```
UPDATE TableName SET location='0' WHERE id='1'
```

It works just fine if I try it from a sqlite browser.

Comment: post your full code, how you open and execute queries.

Comment: If you close Unity and restart it again, does it still happen the first time?